# Picker says setEnableSharedDrives() is not a function

Tags: google-picker

The [Picker reference](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference) updated on April 24th. The subclass `DocsView` now has a function `setEnableSharedDrives()`, but Picker throws an exception and doesn't show the view.

Here it is a sample code:

```
var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
        view.setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST);
        view.setIncludeFolders(true);
        view.setSelectFolderEnabled(true);
        view.setEnableSharedDrives(true);

        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          .addView(view)
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.SUPPORT_DRIVES)
          .hideTitleBar()
          .setSelectableMimeTypes("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
          .setOAuthToken(token)
          .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
          .setCallback(pickerCallback)
          .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
          .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
            DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
          .build();

        picker.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

change setEnableSharedDrives to setEnableDrives

Comment: How did you know this? Do you have a link to an older/different version of the docs? I'm looking at the ones here: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference#DocsView